# Can the creature from a Bag of Tricks make opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, opportunity-attack

The *[bag of tricks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-tricks)* description includes the following:

> You can use an action to pull the fuzzy object from the bag and throw it up to 20 feet. When the object lands, it transforms into a creature you determine by rolling a d8 and consulting the table that corresponds to the bag's color.
> [...]
> The creature is friendly to you and your companions, and it acts on your turn. You can use a bonus action to command how the creature moves and what action it takes on its next turn, or to give it general orders, such as to attack your enemies. In the absence of such orders, the creature acts in a fashion appropriate to its nature.

The creature that you pull from the bag can act on your turn if you use your bonus action to command it. But can it make opportunity attacks?

Since such as thing likely happens on the enemy's turn, you won't be able to command it to with your bonus action, and it says that it acts "appropriate to its nature" if you *don't* give it orders, so can it make opportunity attacks if you do or do not give it orders on your turn (if that makes any difference)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## It *can* make opportunity attacks, but it might not choose to

When you first pull the creature from the bag, it is not necessarily hostile to your enemies, and it might not choose to make opportunity attacks against them.

If you give the creature a general order like "attack my enemies", it should follow that order to the best of its ability for the rest of the combat, including making opportunity attacks.

If you give the creature a more specific order, like "move ten feet north and make a bite attack against that goblin", it might or might not make opportunity attacks against the goblin on subsequent turns after that order is fulfilled.  It would depend on the creature's nature.

Answer (score 10):

## Yes. It makes, and triggers, opportunity attacks

It's a creature and gets all the rights of and privileges of being a creature with actions - including opportunity attacks.

The issue that it begins it's 'life' as a fuzzy object doesn't really matter as it transforms into an actual creature.

Comment: Could you back this up with any citation of game text? I mean the premise that any creature with actions can make OAs.